# Which gives faster query performance on a Microsoft PDW/APS appliance?

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a Microsoft PDW/APS system and we are working with several tables which are almost all <1TB in size. We should not be constrained by the amount of storage space we use.

If our goal is the fastest possible queries are we better off *partitioning* the tables across the compute nodes or *replicating* the tables across the compute nodes?

Comment: That depends entirely on the structure of your data, the types of queries, and the relative speed of your networks, processors, and disk.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The tables are large denormalised flat tables. The exploratory queries we need to be fast are mostly simple GROUP BY and SELECTs involving only a few of the columns. On a parallel data warehouse which gives faster results, partitioning or replicating?

Answer (score 1):

By the documentation it would be replicated tables. That said, if your data and table structure satisfy these two requirements, you should distribute the data 
1. The same key field is used to join all the tables i.e. there is no join incompatibility
2. The join field when hashed produces an even distribution

Partitioning as defined within the APS is an useful technique used to optimize administrative functions (moving/removing/switching) rather than improve performance of queries.